# Which Christian branches/sects have information about their belief system hidden from new members but revealed to established ones?

Tags: denomination-survey, sect

Some religions have what might be described as unpalatable, or at least 'weird' beliefs, from an outside perspective, and sometimes they hide these beliefs from new members and reveal them only to members once they've become well-established in the religion. The most obvious example outside of Christianity is Scientology, which seems to present one face to the outside world and to new members, but a slightly (or significatnly) different world view once you are accepted into it.

This post is notmeant to be judgemental of that practice, for what it's worth, I would just like to know where this pattern exists within Christianity.

Are there any Christian branches which display this type of pattern of behaviour?

I know most do not. As far as I know, there's not any aspect of Catholicism or most branches of Protestant that is deliberately hidden from the outside and only taught to long-standing members. Usually, most churches wear all of their beliefs and practices on their sleeve.

Comment: LDS have some secret/private practices, but I don't know if they have any secret theology.

Comment: @curiousdannii that's fascinating! If you have any links to examples or evidence, I would appreciate that as an answer.

Comment: Part of the trouble with this question that I've just realized is that it's the age of the internet now, so churches which might have had secret knowledge 30 years ago may have had to adapt to the information age and *stop keeping those things secret*. Again pointing to Scientology, where they are no longer capable of keeping their beliefs secret anymore.

Comment: @curiousdannii I wouldn't say secret, but sacred [non lds article](https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=99175018). For example temples have open houses after construction/renovation. Washington DC one has an [open house](https://newsroom.churchofjesuschrist.org/article/washington-dc-temple-open-house-rededication-2022) in April - June 2021 where the public is welcome to come and see

Comment: Ancient Christianity was a mystery religion, and sacraments are still called mysteries in the East and Orient.

Comment: @Lucian could you clarify? Did they hide aspects of their beliefs from the outside world? If so, what sorts of beliefs? I would love a source.

Comment: some bible verses pertaining to mysteries and secrets (things not written) john 20:30, john 21:25, luke 8:10, eph 3:9

Comment: @TKoL: See [Christian mysteries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_mysteries#Christian_mysteries) and [disciplina arcani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disciplina_arcani).

Comment: With respect to Lucian's comment, I've heard the reason why communion (the Eucharist) is "closed" is because originally they would chase out all non-confirmed members and *close* the doors to the sanctuary. That might be apocryphal, however. (Also, the Eucharist has sometimes been derided as cannibalism, for reasons which should be obvious.)

Comment: If people deliberately 'hide' what they believe, it is going to be hard to prove that by documentation/link. I know of a particular doctrine which some quietly hold, throughout 'evangelical' congregations, thinking themselves to be superior with superior 'revelation' but withholding open confession as they know that their doctrine is abhorrent to others. But to prove what is known anecdotally, is not an easy matter.

Comment: Are you asking about secret doctrines and/or theology, or are you asking about secret rules and regulations about discipline - information that is deliberately withheld until after a person signs-up or joins the denomination?

Comment: I think I'm asking about all of it.

Comment: I don't know of any denominations of Christianity that require a person to have a full understanding of their theology before joining. There are certainly things that could affect a person's decision (and these sometimes lead someone to leave the faith) that are not revealed but would be if asked about. The problem is that the new person doesn't know what they should ask about.

Comment: I think part of what drove this question was reading a couple of experiences about one religion in particular. One person was talking about his experience as a missionary for this religion and was basically saying that he felt like he was baptizing people under false pretences because he knew there was information about the religion he wasn't sharing during the conversion process. Not sure if him not sharing those bits of information was seen as a personal choice or a matter of procedure.

Comment: And an instance of a church having certain beliefs unambiguously within their doctrine, but when asked publicly about it the leaders would deny that that's what they believe.

Comment: I won't go into specific details about what religion that is because I didn't come here to answer my own question, but these are the sorts of instances that drove me to ask it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Which Christian branches/sects have information about their belief system hidden from new members but revealed to established ones?**

Historically this has been done in the early days of Christianity. The Early Church practiced this method, in some areas, in order to avoid ridicule, scorn, misunderstanding and possible blasphemy from the part of pagans.

> In parts of the Early Christian Church, many aspects of Christian theology, including some sacraments and sacramentals, the so-called [*disciplina arcani*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disciplina_arcani), were kept hidden from the pagans lest they become objects of ridicule, and were also introduced gradually to catechumens or new converts. As the Age of Persecution ended, the secrecy was gradually relaxed. But the term continued to be used, and the same word is used in the Eastern Orthodox churches to describe "mysteries" and "sacraments". This is not usually so in the West, although theologically many aspects of sacraments are recognized as mysteries in the main sense described above, especially (for those churches accepting it) the doctrine of transubstantiation in the Eucharist. Hence Pope Paul VI's papal encyclical of 3 September 1965 on the Eucharist was titled, from its opening words, [*Mysterium fidei*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysterium_fidei_(encyclical)). In the Roman Rite Catholic Mass within or immediately after the formula of consecration of the wine, the celebrant says "The mystery of faith". Originally the term "Mystery" was used for the sacraments generally in both the East and the West, as shown from the "Mystagogical Homilies" of St. Cyril of Jerusalem and the work, On the Mysteries by St. Ambrose of Milan.
>
> Although all the official doctrines of Christian churches have long been fully public, the loosely defined area of Christian thought called Christian mysticism often concerns the contemplation of sacred mysteries and may include the development of personal theories about them, undertaken in the knowledge that they can never be fully apprehended by man. - [Sacred mysteries (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_mysteries#)

The **Knights of Columbus** within the Catholic Church had have secret initiation ceremonies, but these do not engage on Church beliefs. They are simply keeping their ceremonies secret, thus equating secret to private! In January 2020, the Knights decided to drop their secret initiation ceremonies.(See: [In major change, Knights of Columbus drop secret initiation ceremony](https://www.catholicnewsagency.com/news/43453/in-major-change-knights-of-columbus-drop-secret-initiation-ceremony))

**”Secret”** is not always the best phrase to employ at all times in reference to certain situations within Christianity. For example the the term **secret** for Vatican’s Secret Archives (Library)! A better understanding for the word for ***secretum*** would be **private**.

> The Vatican said on Monday the new name would be the Vatican Apostolic Archives. This removes any potentially “negative nuances” from the Latin word “secretum”, which the pope said in a decree was closer to “private” or “reserved” than “secret” when the archives were first named in about 1610.
>
> They have not been secret in practice for a long time anyway: like most state archives, they are open to qualified researchers after a period of time. The collection of papers, documents and parchments dates as far back as the eighth century, making the archives one of the world’s most important research centres. - [Vatican's Secret Archives no longer officially secret after renaming](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/oct/28/vatican-secret-archives-no-longer-officially-secret-renaming-pope-francis)

Comment: In my opinion, a better translation of secretum in this context is "reserved". Resulting in the name: the Vatican's Reserved Archives.

Comment: Thanks for your input. `the so-called disciplina arcani, were kept hidden from the pagans lest they become objects of ridicule, and were also introduced gradually to catechumens or new converts.` is the sort of thing I'm looking for, fascinating that this sort of thing was going on in Christianity pretty much right away!

Comment: @TKoL No problem! I am still looking for other cases..